# Open Graph on WordPress slideshow page correct og info in head but object debugger registering errors

Tags: php, facebook-opengraph

I am using a custom function to populate the OG info into the head of my page.
If I view the source I can clearly see the correct OG data listed in the head.
[link](http://news.instyle.com/photo-gallery/?postgallery=80633)

```html
<meta property="fb:admins" content="18938064984"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="Send the Trend Launches Celebrity-Inspired Eye Makeup!"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="article"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://news.instyle.com/photo-gallery/"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Instyle.com"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://img2.timeinc.net/instyle/images/2011/wrn/101311-makeup-camilla-383.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
```

However the thumbnail and title do not make it to Facebook news feed.

When I use the object debugger for the page it returns these errors:

> **Warnings That Should Be Fixed**
>
> **Inferred Property**
>   The `og:url` property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
>   **Inferred Property**
>   The `og:title` property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
>   **Inferred Property**
>   The `og:image` property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
>   **Inferred Property**
>   The `og:locale` property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

Clicking the Graph URL link I get this result, title is in-correct and image is an image at the bottom of the page:

```js
{
    "url": "http://news.instyle.com/photo-gallery/",
    "type": "website",
    "title": "Photo Gallery : InStyle.com What's Right Now",
    "image": [
        {
            "url": "http://img2.timeinc.net/instyle/static/i/oba-compliance.png"
        }
    ],
    "updated_time": "2011-10-14T15:20:44+0000",
    "id": "10150121051762663"
}
```

The Facebook links on non-slide show pages is working fine but the OG data is not generated for the slide shows so I had to create this custom function I am trying to get to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're having trouble with Facebook OpenGraph meta tags, the [Facebook Debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) (previously known as the Facebook Linter) is often very helpful — it will force a re-parse of your URL and show you what the OpenGraph parser can see about it.

It has the added benefit of updating Facebook's cached OG metadata for your URL, which is very useful when you've newly updated that content.